# What is the difference of using bsClass and className with react-bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am new to react and could not grasp the concept between bsClass and className.

I try to implement a modified button style, like:

`<Button bsClass="btn-custom" >Custom button</Button>`

where it does not work when I substitute `bsClass` with `className`.

But in other part, using the same custom.css source, I implement:

`<img src={logo} alt="logo" className="app-logo" />` and it works.

Comment: Check the documentation for `Button` component.

Comment: bsClass is predefined. it has its own style to inject on the component. while className needs you to define your css to work

Comment: Ok. Thank you both of you. now I understand the context of the sentence "Base CSS class and prefix for the component. Generally one should only change bsClass to provide new, non-Bootstrap, CSS styles for a component"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JSX attribute `className` is equivalent of HTML `class`. So the below JSX

```
<span className="app-logo">Logo</span>
```

will be equivalent to the below in HTML

```
<span class="app-logo">Logo</span>
```

As per bsClass is considered in

```
<Button bsClass="btn-custom" >Custom button</Button>
```

it is `prop` that is being passed on to the `Button` component in reactJS and that is what it will be using to set the `className` inside the component something like

```
<button className={this.props.bsClass}>{this.props.children}</button>
```

So it an attribute that is defined as a property by the `react-bootstrap` docs.

Comment: It seems to me your example does not explain why a className in the <Button> wouldn't be passed down to the <button> as a class (as it is the case for the <span>).

Comment: @Dabrule, I think I have explained how a className is set in Button component `As per bsClass is considered in

<Button bsClass="btn-custom" >Custom button</Button>
it is prop that is being passed on to the Button component in reactJS and that is what it will be using to set the className inside the component somthing like`

Answer (score 1):

React's `className` is exactly equivalent to regular classes in CSS.

HTML/CSS:

```
<div class='red-text'>
    Foo
</div>
```

React/JSX:

```
<div className='red-text'>
    Foo
</div>
```

The above snippets of code do the exact same thing.  The only reason we're stuck with using `className` in React (instead of `class`) is because "class" was already taken as a reserved keyword in JavaScript.

As the others have said, `bsClass` is a pre-defined class within the react-bootstrap package.  Just like how the CSS-version of Bootstrap comes with its own styling, so, too, does react-bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

A practical difference. I you set bsClass to something other than what REACT-Bootstrap has as a default, you have to do your own css themeing of the button.

By adding a className="xx" you still get the default theme, but you can now add css styles for color, padding, etc, using your own .css

```
.xx {
      magin-bottom: 2px
}
```